# How to move responsive datatable select-checkbox to a different column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, datatables

I am trying to make a responsive table with a selector and I am running into some aesthetic issues. It's looking like this

[image]

Where I want it to like like this:

[image]

And have the green plus show up in the last name right before `Wilson`

I'm figuring it's an easy fix but I can't seem to find it

Here is html:

```
 <table id="LastWeek" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th><img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/Shopping-Cart-9.png" alt="shopping cart" style="width:20px;height:15px"></th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
              {% for p in qbPastWeek %}
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="{{p.player.profile_url}}">{{p.player.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{p.player.first_name}}</td>

        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#LastWeek').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    } ],
    select: {
        style:    'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[ 8, 'desc' ]]

    });
```